# Getting "parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Ctx'" error

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am following this **Microsoft document** [Remove-AzStorageBlob (Az.Storage) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/remove-azstorageblob?view=azps-7.5.0)
I am trying to delete a blob including above command in PowerShell function like below:

```
$rgName="*******"  
$storage="******"  
$container="*****"  
$blob="my_blob_name"  
Connect-AzAccount  
Function DeleteBlob  
{  
$storage=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $storage  
$ctx=$storage.Ctx  
Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container $container -Ctx $ctx -Blob $blob  
}  
DeleteBlob
```

After running the above script, I am getting the below error:

```
Remove-AzStorageBlob : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Ctx'.  
At line:21 char:52  
+ Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container $container -Ctx $ctx -Blob $b ...  
+ ~~~~  
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-AzStorageBlob], ParameterBindingException  
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.RemoveStorageAzureBlobCommand
```

Did anyone face the error like above, please help me solving the error.

Comment: Please check your code and try replacing 'ctx' with 'Context'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that **`Ctx`** doesn't exist in PowerShell.
To resolve the error, try replacing **`Ctx`** with **`Context`** .

***I tried the same in my environment by modifying the script like below and got the results successfully:***

```
$resourceGroupName="*******"
$storageAccName="******"
$containerName="*****"
$blobName="my_blob_name"
Connect-AzAccount
Function DeleteBlob
{
$storageAcc=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName
$ctx=$storageAcc.Context
Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx -Blob $blobName
}
DeleteBlob
```

***Before running the above script, I have blob in my Portal like below:***

[image]

[image]

***After running the above script, the **blob got deleted successfully** like below:***

[image]